# ERROR: No matching distribution found for mkl-service==2.3.0. (GCP, EC2)

Tags: python-3.x, deployment, intel-mkl

[Please click to check the error SS here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bGQ9.png)

I have checked the **`mkl-service`** PyPI. There are only 2 versions available, *2.4.0 (May 27, 2021) and 2.3.0 (Feb 3, 2021)*. When I try to deploy my ML project by creating EC2 instance or on GCP, when libraries from requirements.txt are getting installed THIS `mkl-fft`, `mkl-random` and `mkl-service` give errors for using their higher versions. I then used older versions of `mkl-fft==1.0.6`, `mkl-random==1.0.1.1` But for `mkl-service` both the versions available are the latest and thus giving errors I think. What is the alternative? Or where can I get the older version of `mkl-service`?

Also, on my local machine, there is not an issue regarding the latest versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conda instead of pip to install the mkl.

```html
conda install -c intel mkl-service
```

or

```
conda install -c conda-forge mkl-service
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using Python version 3 will give such errors. I resolved it after using 3.6

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).